# SQL how to group by year end

Tags: sql

I am not well advanced in SQL. Maybe someone could help me with this little problem.
I need to summarize data  by year end. I know I can use

```
SELECT Year(Mydate) as year,
       Sum(Amount)  as amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY Year(Mydate)
```

Mydate here is full date column (i.e. 15/6/2020). However in this case I get year as year number. I need to get year as year end date, i.e. 12/31/2021. How can I do that?

Comment: try with `DATE_FORMAT(Mydate,'%Y-12-31')`

Comment: 1) tag your database  2) provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Date functions and usage varies between databases. Tag your database.

Comment: Database is MS SQL Server 2019. It does not accept DATE_FORMAT, but accepts FORMAT. However %Y does not seem to work. I get Y-12-31 in every row after using

SELECT FORMAT(Mydate,'%Y-12-31')  AS year

Answer (score 0):

Try format your field using DATE_FORMAT: (DATE_FORMAT(Mydate, '%Y/12/31')

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
  Year(Mydate) as year, 
  Convert(datetime, Str(Year(Mydate)) + ' Dec 31', 103) as eoyDec31a
  Convert(char(10), Convert(datetime, Str(Year(Mydate)) + ' Dec 31', 103), 103) As eoyDec31b,
  Max(Mydate) As eoyMax,
  Sum(Amount)  as amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY 
  Year(Mydate), 
  Convert(datetime, Str(Year(Mydate)) + ' Dec 31', 103),
  Convert(char(10), Convert(datetime, Str(Year(Mydate)) + ' Dec 31', 103), 103) 
Order By 1
```

If Dec 31 occurs in the table for every year, just the eoyMax column will do. If not  the end of year has to be created from the parts: 2012 dec 31 etc.

eoyDec31a is the american format and eoyDec31b is the date string in british format.

The Convert function converts from string to datetime and back.

Comment: This works on Sql Server 7, Sql Server 2005 and upwards

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to solve my issue:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(Year(Mydate),12,31)  AS year,
       Sum(Amount)  as amount
FROM table1
GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(Year(Mydate),12,31)
```